# Allow text box only uppercase, lowercase letters and space in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to make a text box allow only lowercase(a-z), uppercase(A-Z) letters and space using jQuery.

When I searching it on here I found this code, but it allow only lowercase letters.

```
<input name="lorem" class="alphaonly">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.alphaonly').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); }
);
</script>
```

So I tried it using `/[^a-zA-Z ]/g` But I couldn't figure it out.

Hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `i` flag on the Regex to make it case-insensitive and `\s` to allow spaces. Finally you can also use a function to amend the current value, to save having to cache the selector. Try this:

```
$('.alphaonly').bind('keyup blur', function() { 
    $(this).val(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace(/[^a-z\s]/gi,''); 
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ze5xefdr/)

Depending on your jQuery version you should also change `bind()` to `on()`.

Comment: I added an example for you.

Comment: One question, Can You tell me how can I update this pattern for numbers and hyphen `[0-9-]`

Comment: You can just add them to the character set: `.replace(/[^a-z\s\d-]/gi, '');`. The `\d` = `0-9`.

Comment: only for numbers and hyphen?

Comment: If you only want number and hyphen then what you had should work: `.replace(/[^\d-]/gi, '');`

Comment: `/gi` mean what? is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = /^[a-z]+$/;
```

That pattern will match one or more lower-case alphabetic characters, and no other characters.